# changing z-index and get a scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried a lot of things, first in the css now with jquery but i can't get the z-index correct.
The text should go over the image that is on the right side of it and not under it.
If i check the z-index in the source then it's correct but still the text is on the back.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var entries = $('.entrie').length;


    $('.entrie').each(function(index){
        //console.log(index);
        var newIndex = entries-index;
        console.log(newIndex);
        $(this).css('z-index', newIndex);
    });


});
```

here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EJMqG/

2nd (less important), when i make the window really small then the text goes under the image, how can i prevent this? I just want scrollbars when it gets to small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give both elements you are applying z-index to a `position:relative;`. z-index doesn't work on anything that doesn't have a position.

Answer (score 1):

Add "position:absolute;" in entrieInfo class and "position:relative;" in entrieImage class.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cX8Fy/1/

Comment: Just to complement:
 "Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)."
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)